# How should I configure my view for getting window.parent value in MVC?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, iframe, razor

I was given this html form content so I can adjust my razor view to set my hidden value and run correctly, but I don't get any value set so far with what I have. In the iframe within my view this is the content I have:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="ThirdPartyHandler.aspx.vb" Inherits="ThirdPartyHandler" %>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Welcome</title>    
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    <!--
        function valuesSet() {
            try
            {
                window.parent.document.MyForm.MyHiddenValue.value = "true";
                window.parent.document.MyForm.submit();
            }
            catch(err)
            {
                //Silently Swallow any Error here as we may not be in a hosted container with a listening form...
            }
        }
    //-->
    </script>

</head>
<body onload = "valuesSet();">
<h1><br /><br />Thank you.</h1>
<input type="hidden" name="MyHiddenFormComplete" value="true" />
</body>
</html>
```

So that is all from iframe content which sits on cross domain, not in my application.

Now in my razor view I'm trying something like this:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { name = "MyForm", id = "MyForm" }))
{
<div class="row">
    <iframe id="frame" src = '@Model.SecureUrl' width = "100%" 
            height="360px" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
    <input type="hidden" name="MyHiddenValue" />
</div>
}
```

What I'm expecting to happen is that when the valuesSet() function is executed in the iframe, my local 'MyHiddenValue' hidden field will set the value to 'True', but that doesn't happen. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "So that is all from iframe content which sits on cross domain, not in my application."

That's your problem. You cannot get/change any content between two different domains via client side code. If you could, it would be a very big secure problem to the browsers.

Imagine that I could have in my website any iframe pointing to another website (let's suppose the Gmail website), and I could manipulate things there, to get some personal information about the user (supposing he's logged into his Google account in that browser).

You won't be able to do this.

There is a workaround, though:

- Your partner should call some server-side page of your site, for example:

  ```
  function valuesSet() {
      location.href = "http://yoursite.com/?myhiddenvalue=true";
  }
  ```
- Your server-side page should do something like:

  ```
  <body onload="loaded();">

  <script type="text/javascript">
      function loaded() {
          window.parent.document.MyForm.MyHiddenValue.value = getParameterByName("myhiddenvalue");
          window.parent.document.MyForm.submit();
      }

      function getParameterByName(name) {
          name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
          var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
          results = regex.exec(location.search);
          return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ""));
      }
  </script>
  ```

Doing this, you'll avoid the cross-domain client-side secure issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, just to let you know, I'm trying to edit value within my application, so why do you think that the window.parent.document.MyForm.MuhiddenValue.value can't be set that way? With JS function from the iframe? Because I think that's the role of that method? Thanks for your help

Comment: You said that this iframe "sits on cross domain, not in my application", and if that's true, the iframe is in another domain, it cannot change your parent window via client side code. That's why this iframe - instead of trying to manipulate your stuff cross-domain client-side based - it should redirect to some page inside your domain (with a querystring, for example), and this page should manipulate your main page via client side, cause as it's inside your domain, browsers will let you do that.